# Can you do this question without matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: question]

Can I use the formula for a trapezium? I'm not really sure where to start

Comment: Have you tried drawing a diagram?

Comment: yep, now I see I dropped parallels, not perpendicular to the x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

$$\small{A=\frac{b_1+b_3}{2}\cdot (a_3-a_1)+\frac{b_3+b_2}{2}\cdot (a_2-a_3)-\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}\cdot (a_2-a_1)}$$
I leave the rest work to you.

Comment: ahh I see. But what if A1 and A2 had the same y-coordinate? The bottom portion would be a rectangle I think that would mess up the working out when misusing. Is that correct?

Comment: ahh I see. But what if A1 and A2 had the same y-coordinate? The bottom portion would be a rectangle I think that would mess up the working out when misusing. Is that correct?

Comment: nope, no messing up, the formula will be the same for $b_1=b_2$.

Comment: I see. The formula for a trapezium works for rectangles! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $$f(A_1,A_2,A_3) = f(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3) = \frac12(a_1b_2-a_2b_1+a_2b_3-a_3b_2+a_3b_1-a_1b_3)$$ the function on the LHS. Check algebraically that this expression is invariant on translations, i.e. for any $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ we have
$$f(a_1+x,b_1+y,a_2+x,b_2+y,a_3+x,b_3+y)=f(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3).$$
This means we can translate our triangle $A_1A_2A_3$ into the first quadrant so we can WLOG assume that our triangle is in the first quadrant.

If the points $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ are positioned anticlockwise as in @farruhota's answer we get that the area is indeed
$f(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ and in particular we have $f(A_1,A_2,A_3) > 0$.

Now show again algebraically that $f$ is invariant under cyclical rotations
$$f(A_1,A_2,A_3) = f(A_3,A_1,A_2)=f(A_2,A_3,A_1)$$
so the formula holds for any anticlockwise arrangement.

On the other hand, for clockwise arrangements we have
$$f(A_1,A_3,A_2) = f(A_2,A_1,A_3) = f(A_3,A_2,A_1) = -f(A_1,A_2,A_3)$$
so this is again the area of the triangle but with negative sign.

Comment: I see. Is this also suitable for proof to this question? As in just (1,2,3)=(1,1,2,2,3,3)
therefore 1/2(12−21+23−32+31−13)

Comment: @basura What do you mean?

Comment: Is what you wrote a suitable answer or is it just extra information?

Comment: @basura It's not a suitable answer by itself because you still need to prove that for a triangle in the first quadrant with anticlockwise vertices $A_1,A_2,A_3$ its area is equal to $f(A_1,A_2,A_3)$.